# Linux Libertine small caps fail for some Unicode characters

Tags: xetex, small-caps, libertine

I'm using XeTeX and Linux Libertine, since I want "true" small caps.
However it seems that the small caps don't work for certain Unicode characters. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
h ħ ö Ö H Ħ

\scshape{h} \scshape{ö} \scshape{ħ}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get in my PDF (using `latexmk -xelatex`):

[image: Small caps fails with some Unicode characters]

I am using the latest OTF versions of Libertine (downloaded just now). When I try this sequence on the [Linux Libertine live-renderer](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1), the smallcaps ħ is displayed correctly:

[image: Screenshot from Linux Libertine live-renderer]

So this must be a Xetex thing. Any ideas?

Comment: The web page says 'Every font of the Libertine Open Fonts Project contains a set of small capitals in the so called private use area (PUA) which can be addressed by OpenType capable software.' The PUA is a 'free for all': I'm not expert enough to be sure, but I's say that putting the glyphs here is the issue.

Comment: So is there any way to get XeteX to use the glyphs in this PUA? I've seen it alluded to but it seems to be discouraged and I cannot find any code for how to actually do it.

Comment: The font simply does not have small cap substitution for ħ. No idea what the live render is using, but looks like a standalone small caps font, which might have different coverage than the regular one.

Comment: Yes, the page [here](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=91&L=1) seems to indicate that there should be a separate small-caps font with an `S` suffix, but I could find no such file in any of the packages they offer for download.

Comment: To get any glyph actually available in the otf, use \libertineGlyph{unicode} as provided in libertine.sty; e.g., \libertineGlyph{hbar} \libertineGlyph{uni04E7}

Comment: There are S fonts in the LinLibertineTTF_5.1.3 package.

Comment: Hmm, so there are! Although it seems they still do not have the small-caps glyphs I want. I guess the live-renderer is just faking it somehow...

Comment: @KhaledHosny An answer?

Answer (score 4):

The font simply doesn't have small caps substitution for `ħ`. Probably the font viewing software is able to fake the glyph or take it from the PUA.